Why Modified Newtonian dynamics is not tested with modern gravimeters?
According to Wikipedia, Standard Newtonian gravity might not hold for smaller than $10^{-10}\  \mathrm{m/s^2}$ accelerations and Modified Newtonian Dynamics might explain the differences. If I understand right, it is argued that in such accelerations gravity might be boosted tens of percents.
Even a few kilograms could create such acceleration and to my understanding, most advanced modern relative gravimeters have sensitivities at least in the $10^{-11}\  \mathrm{ms^{−2}}$ range. I would guess testing this kind of hypothesis would be easy, but I did not find any such tests by googling. Would anyone know why is that?

Which Wikipedia page?

The main reason is transportation and automation costs. For testing MOND it would not be sufficient to measure small differences in a strong gravitational field. Instead, it is necessary to go to where the gravitational field is weak. This would involve transporting the apparatus further than we have ever transported anything.
